# find space in string postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, space

How to find space after words in postgresql:

I have two same strings in my database :

```
string1
  string1
```

I am trying to find the one with 2 spaces before and one space after.

here are some of the queries I used with their results:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "column" LIKE '__string1_';  -->   *no result*
SELECT * FROM part1 WHERE "column" LIKE '__string1%';
```

Results:

```
1)  string1 and xyx

2)  string1 and string2

3)  string1
```

but I only need string1 with no strings after or before.

Comment: why don't you just use like `'  string1'`?

Comment: some test input and output would be nice

Answer (score 3):

I will just complement the above answer:

Suppose you want to find any space in the column **Name** in the **demo** table, then the code would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM demo 
WHERE Name LIKE '% %'
ORDER BY Name
```

Now, if you want any string 'a' for example inside the column, you would just have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM demo 
WHERE Name LIKE '%a%'
ORDER BY Name
```

and also, for words that begin with a space, you would just use '_' (in a certain position):

```
SELECT * FROM demo 
WHERE Name LIKE '_a%'
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

There are likely several ways to accomplish this. See [PostgreSQL's pattern matching documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) for some examples.

However, I use `%` to find patterns: `select * from table where column ILIKE '%string1%';` would return anything with string1 in it, including the cols with spaces.

You can also try escaping the spaces: `select * from table where column ILIKE '\ \ string1\ ';`

or, even simpler `select * from table where column ILIKE '  string1';`

I also use the case insensitive `ILIKE` as an alternative for a case sensitive `LIKE`, so case will not matter in your query.

Comment: If I use % I am getting results like: "string1 and string2" but I only need string1 . If I use escaping the space I am getting this error :ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'\\string1\';" and for the ' string1' I got no result.

Comment: You shouldn't get string 2 with % unless you remove the 1 and place the % in its place - i.e. string%. You would return string 12 however as % matches anything after the provided string, or before depending on if its the pre or postfix. the `\ ` is an escape character, so its escaping the space and ensures it gets processed as a character and not whitespace. Ensure its `\ \ `(there is a space between the slashes and one after).

Comment: Is there a specific use case for the spaces though, couldn't you just trim the data to ensure spaces are removed if required?